# How to label inner/outer of contour when slice/rasterize 3D objects to image stack?

Tags: python, vtk, rasterize, 3d-printing, image-slicer

For 3D printing, we slice the digital objects into image stacks in order to stack them layer by layer using a 3D printer. And when the slice is done, how to label the inner/outer to set the solid parts?

1. The STL model:

[image]

2. The Slices:

[image]

3. Sample of one image stack (sliced):

[image]

but the need is to keep or label the inner/outer of contours, say the inner is black so the 3D printer will print it and skip the white outer. The goal is filled inner of contours as the following image:

[image]

### Try 1

```
import pyvista as pv

mesh = pv.read('./haus.stl')
slices = mesh.slice_along_axis(n=20, axis='z', progress_bar=True) 

# show single slice with camera setting
slices[15].plot(cpos=[0, 1, 1], line_width=5, parallel_projection=True,)

# save slices (outcome is as step.3 image stack)
for i in range(20):
    p = pv.Plotter(off_screen=True)
    p.add_mesh(slices[i])
    p.camera_position = 'zy'
    p.enable_parallel_projection()
    im_name = "im_slice_" + str(i) + ".jpg"
    p.screenshot(im_name)


# Try voxelize (as ans from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75300529)
voxels = pv.voxelize(mesh, density=mesh.length / 100)

# Try pv.Plane() (not test yet)
plane=pv.Plane()
plane.compute_implicit_distance(mesh, inplace=True)
np.sign(plane.point_data['implicit_distance'])
#i_resolution=?, j_resolution=?


# Try vtk (not test yet)
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68191368
```

voxelize model:
[image]

voxelize sliced:
[image]

but `voxelize sliced` doesn't seem very suitable. A very fine mesh needs to be built to restore the boundaries.

### Try 2 [VTK example](https://kitware.github.io/vtk-examples/site/Python/PolyData/PolyDataContourToImageData/)

show STL:

[image]

Just add STL reader and Mapper:

```
filename = './haus.stl'
    
reader = vtkSTLReader()
reader.SetFileName(filename)
reader.Update()

stlMapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
stlMapper.SetInputConnection(reader.GetOutputPort())
polydata = stlMapper
print("Get GetOrigin", polydata.GetCenter()) 
sphereSource = reader
```

slice result:

[image]

Try 2 is almost done with the job, but can not figure out the SetExtent/SetOrigin effect. The output image all fit to the contours' dimensions so each output image WXH is not identical.

### Try 3 [3D Silcer example](https://slicer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/developer_guide/script_repository/models.html#rasterize-a-model-and-save-it-to-a-series-of-image-files)

Only change some code as following:

```
inputModelFile = "./data/haus.stl"
outputDir = "./outputs/"
...
for i in range(80,140, 10):
  imageio.imwrite(f"{outputDir}/image_{i:03}.jpg", 255 - outputLabelmapVolumeArray[i]) # Inverting Colors
```

[image]

The result seems acceptable, but need future to revise some code to match the resolution, position, spacing, etc. So, is there a more lean and more efficient way to automate similar work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try out the combination of `vtkFeatureEdges`, `vtkStripper` and  `vtkTriangleFilter`, eg:

```py
from vedo import *
msh = Mesh('https://vedo.embl.es/examples/data/cow.vtk')
slices = []
for z in np.arange(-.50, .50, .15):
    line = msh.clone().cut_with_plane(origin=(0,0,z), normal='z')
    cap = line.cap(True)
    slices.append(cap)
show(slices, msh.alpha(0.1), axes=1)
```

[image]

In case you want to create a set of images or a tiff stack (instead of a polygonal mesh), you can do it with:

```py
from vedo import *

surf = Mesh("https://vedo.embl.es/examples/data/cow.vtk")
surf.compute_normals()

# write a tiff stack
vol = surf.binarize(spacing=(0.02, 0.02, 0.02))
vol.alpha([0,0.6]).c('blue5')
vol.write("image.tif")

# write a numpy array and/or a set of png files
arr = vol.tonumpy()
pic = Picture(arr[:,:,55])
pic.write("slice55.png")

show(vol, pic, N=2, sharecam=False, axes=1)
```

[image]

Finally you can inspect the tiff file from command line:

```bash
vedo --slicer3d image.tif
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @mmusy. It did the job. But it has the same issue as Try-2 VTK,  "The output image all fit to the contours' dimensions, so each output image WXH is not identical." is it possible manually control the space padding for each plane to fit the output image size?

Comment: You don't need padding, the contour coordinates are absolute, they are not shifted wrt the original shape. The "padding" is trivially given by the difference of the bounds.

Comment: can you get the output of the sliced image, just for example?

Comment: yes - you can write it to disk with eg. `cap.write("capmesh.stl")`.

Comment: Thanks, @mmusy, I mean the "image" output as the original question. It would be great if you could provide the workable code.

Comment: I updated the above answer.